PhpWord неправильно сохраняет docx документ теряя графики и таблицы
require __DIR__ .  '/../../PhpOffice/vendor/autoload.php';
//require 'Agreement.php';

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('Z.docx', 'Word2007');

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('names.docx', 'Word2007');

В файле Z.docx есть таблицы и диаграммы, но при выполнении кода я получаю файл names.docx без таблиц и диаграмм только текст.

Аналогичную ошибку я получал в PhpExcel. Выяснилось, что картинки при загрузке файла необходимо загружать и выводить "вручную". Автоматически они не загружаются. Возможно, и здесь так же.

Просто нужно .docx файл конвертировать в HTML, а затем в PDF.
